# Create mysql column with Key=MUL?

Tags: mysql

I want to make a column with key = mul. What should I add to the following statement to make it do that?

```
alter table skills_required add column skill_id int (11) NOT NULL;
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add a [non-primary key](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) on the field:

```
alter table skills_required add column skill_id int (11) NOT NULL
                          , add key ( skill_id )
```

Comment: how to  create table using mul key instead of altering it